# Is there a Way to customize "Graphical summary" of survey?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, survey, statistics

I have a simple satisfaction Survey in SharePoint 2013

4 Questions with radial answer from 1-10
1 Question With text box

In Graphical summary of responses SP display:
% graph of every radial reply 
and % of text replies

I would like to remove graphical chart for text responses.

I need also to treat data directly in SharePoint 
Is there a possibility to display on the page:

Average, medium, count of replies, and sort them by date?